# Having trouble with pythonic style and list comprehension

Tags: python, list, coding-style, list-comprehension

I spent yesterday writing a small script in Python, which is not my primary language, and it left me with some questions on how to do things in proper 'pythonic' style. The task is fairly simple, I have two arrays `fieldnames` and `values`. Imagine their contents are

```
fieldnames = ['apples','oranges','pears','bananas']
values = [None,2,None,5]
```

I need to create an array of fieldnames that only consists of indices that correspond with values that are not None. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
#print fieldnames
usedFieldnames = []

for idx,val in enumerate(values):
    if val is not None:
        usedFieldnames.append(fieldnames[idx])
```

I could be wrong, but this seems very non-pythonic to me, and I was wondering if there was a more python-appropriate way to do this with a list comprehension. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate through a list and get the index of the current item at the same time.

```
print [idx for idx, field in enumerate(fieldnames) if values[idx] is not None]
# [1, 3]
```

If you want the fieldnames, then

```
print [field for idx, field in enumerate(fieldnames) if values[idx] is not None]
# ['oranges', 'bananas']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> fieldnames = ['apples','oranges','pears','bananas']
>>> values = [None,2,None,5]
>>> [field for field, value in zip(fieldnames, values) if value is not None]
['oranges', 'bananas']
```

If you are using python2.x, instead of `zip()`, which creates a new list with zipped lists, you can take an "iterative" approach and use [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> [field for field, value in izip(fieldnames, values) if value is not None]
['oranges', 'bananas']
```

In case of python3.x, `zip()` returns an iterator, not a list.

Comment: Would you say `zip` in this case creates an unnecessary list?

Comment: You might want to use `izip`

Comment: Remember that `zip` doesn't create an unnecessary list if you're using Python 3, and beginners should probably be using 3 anyway.

Comment: In most cases, the optimization of using `itertools.izip` is premature/unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

An example for storing even numbers in a list using list comprehension in python3:

```
even_number_collection = [ num for num in range(20) if num%2==0]

# one way to print above list
print(*even_number_collection,sep=" ")

# another way
for a in even_number_collection:
    print(a, end=" ")
```

You can read from here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/